# R ggplot2 Add today's date to the title

Tags: r, string, ggplot2

In principle, I'm sure this is straightforward....

How do I append today's date to my ggplot title?

```
today.date <- Sys.Date() 
labs(title='Daily New COVID-19 Hospitalizations as of ', x=....)
```

In other words, what's the R / ggplot syntax to append today.date to my plot title? Am  I better off using ggtitle rather than labs for the title -- does that make it easier?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried with `title = paste('Daily New COVID-19 Hospitalizations as of', today.date, sep = " ")`?

Comment: That works, David! Post the above as an answer rather than comment and I'll give you answer credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both with `labs` and `ggtitle` you can use function `paste()` as follows:

```
labs(title = paste('Daily New COVID-19 Hospitalizations as of', today.date, sep = " "))
```

or

```
ggtitle(paste('Daily New COVID-19 Hospitalizations as of', today.date, sep = " "))
```